# Preventing a async load function from being called repetitively in a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a callback function that loads a page of data at a time.   The function gets called/triggered when the back and next links are clicked.   I run into issues with the animation and the load completing in time when the end user does fast, subsequent clicks of next link and repetitively calls the load function.   I realize that this is an async call, but is there a way to queue or pause the loads/animations so that one load is not running before the other one is finished?

```
  function NextPageNav_Click() {
      var CurPage = parseInt($('#CurPage').attr('value').toString()) + 1;
      $('#CurPage').attr('value', CurPage);
      loadPage(CurPage, 'Next');
  }


  function loadPage(CurPage, State) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "defaulttmp3.aspx/GetLatestProfiles",
          cache: true,
          async: false,
          data: "{'PageIndex': " + CurPage + "}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (msg) {


              switch (State) {

                  case 'Previous':
                      $('<div id="nextitems"></div>').insertBefore('#curitems');
                      $('#nextitems').empty();
                      $('#nextitems').setTemplateURL('page/public/templates/profiletemplate.htm');
                      $('#nextitems').processTemplate(msg);
                      $('#items').attr('style', 'left:-920px');
                      $('#items').animate({
                          "left": "+=920px"
                      }, 500, function () {

                          $('#curitems').remove();
                          $('#nextitems').attr('id', 'curitems');
                      }

                      );

                      break;

                  case 'Next':

                      $('<div id="nextitems"></div>').insertAfter('#curitems');
                      $('#nextitems').empty();
                      $('#nextitems').setTemplateURL('page/public/templates/profiletemplate.htm');
                      $('#nextitems').processTemplate(msg);
                      $('#items').animate({
                          "left": "-=920px"
                      }, 500, function () {
                         $('#curitems').remove();
                         $('#nextitems').attr('id', 'curitems');
                         $('#items').attr('style', 'left:0');
                      }

                      );
                   break;  
                  default:
                      $('#curitems').empty();
                      $('#curitems').setTemplateURL('page/public/templates/profiletemplate.htm');
                      $('#curitems').processTemplate(msg);
                      break;

              }


              var RowsReturned = parseInt(msg.d.RowsReturned.toString());
              var PageSize = parseInt(msg.d.PageSize.toString());
              initPrevNextLinks(RowsReturned, PageSize, CurPage);



          },
          error: function (request, status, error) {
              alert(request.statusText);
          }

      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

rather, try throttling the click

```
var throttleAsync(callback, time) {
     var timeoutId = null;
     return function() {
           clearTimeout(timeoutId);
           timoeoutId = setTimeout(callback, time || 1);
     };
}
```

---

**EDIT**

the previous resets it per call, however to use the first click & ignore subsequent clicks

```
var throttleAsync(callback, time) {
     var timeoutId = null;
     return function() {
           if(timeoutId == null) {
                timoeoutId = setTimeout(function() { timeoutId = null; callback; }, time || 1);
           }
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the previous animation before starting the next one, you can do so using the `.stop()` jQuery function like this:

```
$('#items').stop(true, true).animate(...);
```

The options for `.stop()` control what happens to the stopped animation, but if you just want it to jump to the end and be done, you probably want `.stop(true, true)`.

In your particular case, you probably also have to worry about queued up ajax calls that may not have completed yet before the next click comes through.  In that case, you can either keep a flag for whether an ajax call is in flight and ignore any clicks that come through then or you can try to abort the currently in-flight ajax call using `.abort()` as shown [here](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/09/29/jquery-stop-an-ajax-call/).

I'd probably recommend just ignoring any button presses while an ajax call is already in progress since going faster that the results come in is probably not all that useful.